# A Special Pair of Models for ZFC (New Version)

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, open-problems, forcing

Are there two models $M$ and $N$ for $\text{ZFC}$ such that:

**(1)** $M\subseteq N$

**(2)** $\aleph_{1}^{N}=\aleph_{1}^{M}$

**(3)** $\aleph_{2}^{N}=\aleph_{\omega +1}^{M}$

**Update:** According to Peter's useful answer it seems this problem is still open. So my question is about "partial" or "similar" results with different (but not too different) $\aleph$s. Please give me some references too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Péter indicates, this is open. It is related to a question that is a favorite of many. Shelah has conjectured that if $M\subseteq N$ are (proper class transitive) models of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $\kappa$ is a cardinal in $M$ with succesor $\lambda$, and $\lambda$ is a cardinal in $N$, then in $N$ we have that $\mathrm{cf}(|\kappa|)=\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$. Note that if there are two models as you inquire, then $\kappa=\aleph_\omega^M$ contradicts Shelah's conjecture.

Shelah himself proved his conjecture in some cases, namely when, in $M$, $\kappa$ is either regular, or a singular such that $\square_\kappa$ holds. In fact, his proof naturally splits into two parts:

1. Under either assumption, in $M$, the combinatorial principle that we now call $ADS_\kappa$ holds.
2. If $M\subseteq N$, $(\kappa^+)^M$ is a cardinal of $N$, and $ADS_\kappa$ holds in $M$, then in $N$, $\mathrm{cf}(|\kappa|)=\mathrm{cf}(\kappa)$.

Here, $ADS_\kappa$ is the statement that there is an Almost Disjoint sequence of Sets, in the following sense: A sequences $(A_\alpha\mid\alpha<\kappa^+)$ such that each $A_\alpha$ is an unbounded subset of $\kappa$, and there are functions $g_\beta:\beta\to\kappa$ for all $\beta<\kappa^+$ such that for each such $\beta$, we have that $(A_\alpha\setminus g_\beta(\alpha)\mid\alpha<\beta)$ is a sequences of pairwise disjoint sets.

This appears in the **Cardinal arithmetic** book, Lemma 4.9 in Chapter VII (page 304), where Shelah remarks that we can also assume instead of 1. that, in $M$, $\kappa$ is singular and $\mathrm{pp}(\kappa)>\kappa^+$.

James Cummings, and later Cummings-Foreman-Magidor have studied Shelah's conjecture. The key references are

> James Cummings. [*Collapsing successors of singulars*](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1997-125-09/S0002-9939-97-03995-6/S0002-9939-97-03995-6.pdf), Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., **125 (9)**, (1997), 2703–2709. [MR1416080 (97j:03091)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1416080),

and

> James Cummings, Matthew Foreman, and Menachem Magidor. [*Squares, scales and stationary reflection*](http://www.math.cmu.edu/users/jcumming/papers/jpaper.pdf), J. Math. Log., **1 (1)**, (2001), 35–98. [MR1838355 (2003a:03068)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1838355).

Cummings-Foreman-Magidor prove that rather than square, assuming the weak square principle $\square^*_\kappa$ or the existence of a very good scale suffice. Cummings shows that there are many difficulties in obtaining models contradicting Shelah's conjecture. He also indicates a specific way that one could violate the conjecture and in fact reach your setting, namely, if one has that $$ (\aleph_{\omega+1},\aleph_\omega)\twoheadrightarrow(\aleph_2,\aleph_1) $$ and there is a Woodin cardinal $\delta$. The specific instance of Chang's conjecture needed here is open. It implies that $\{X\subseteq\aleph_{\omega+1}\mid \mathrm{ot}(X)=\aleph_2\}$ is stationary, so we can force with the full stationary tower (for $\delta$) below this set, and $V,V[G]$ is a model of your situation.

Additional later work by Cummings-Foreman-Magidor (on "canonical structure") indicates further difficulties.

Comment: Thanks Andres, Your answer is comprehensive and helpful. Can you indicate some theorems similar to what I described above with different $\aleph$s?

Comment: Dima Sinapova is writing a paper "Collapsing singular cardinals" that might be relevant. I'm not aware of her results. Does anyone know what is she proving in her paper?

Answer (score 10):

That's a famous unsolved problem. 
L. Bukovsky, E. Coplakova-Hartova: Minimal collapsing extension of models of ZFC, Annals of Pure and Applies Logic, 46(1990), 265-298. 0

Comment: Thank you Peter. So the question is still unsolved. Is there any partial or similar result? I am looking for possible methods which are possibly useful for solving this problem. Perhaps such solution could be a combination (or generalization) of solutions for similar results.

Answer (score 6):

I add a few more remarks to Prof. Caicedo's nice answer:

Suppose $V \subset W$, $\aleph_{1}^W=\aleph_{1}^V$ and $\aleph_2^W=\aleph_{\omega+1}^V$. Then

1) In $V,$ SCH holds at $\aleph_\omega$,

2) There is a $V$-stationary subset $\aleph_{\omega+1}^V$ which is not $W$-stationary,

3) There exists in $W$ an $\omega$-sequence of elements of $\aleph_\omega^V$ which is not
in $V$.

4) $W$ is not a forcing extension of $V$ by a proper forcing notion.

For more information see Cummings paper "Two Results in Combinatorial Set Theory".

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your question about the situation at other $\aleph$s: Lemma 3.1 from Cummings' paper "Collapsing successors of singulars," together with the fact (due to Shelah, I believe) that, if $\overrightarrow{f}$ is a scale of length $\aleph_{\omega+1}$, then there is a club $C$ in $\aleph_{\omega+1}$ such that every $\alpha \in C \cap \mathrm{cof}(\geq \aleph_4)$ is good for $\overrightarrow{f}$, yields that, if $5 \leq n < \omega$, then there cannot be inner models $V\subset W$ such that $\aleph_{\omega+1}^V = \aleph_n^W$.

Also, to add to the list of restrictions your desired situation would impose on $V$ and $W$ already given by Andres and Mohammad, it follows from results of Sharon and Viale from their paper "Some consequences of reflection on the approachability ideal" that if $V\subset W$ are inner models and $\aleph_{\omega+1}^V = \aleph_n^W$ for some $n<\omega$, then, in $W$, a form of simultaneous stationary reflection must fail at $\aleph_n^W$. More precisely, in $W$, for all stationary $S\subseteq \aleph_n^W$, there are $\{S_i \mid i<\omega \}$ such that each $S_i$ is a stationary subset of $S$ and there is no $\alpha < \aleph_n^W$ such that each $S_i$ reflects at $\alpha$. (Note that this is trivial if $n=1$, since no stationary subsets of $\aleph_1$ reflect.)